# What's a morphism between algebraic structures of different types?

Tags: terminology, morphism

## Background

I had originally posted this question as:

> Among [morphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism) there are [homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) that are structure-preserving maps between algebraic structures of the **same** type. What's a conventional term for a structure-preserving map between algebraic structures of **different** types?

However it has been pointed out to me that this original question is flawed in its assumptioned. To salvage this question into something coherent, and valuable to users of math.SE I will give some explanation of why I found this terminology confusing.

## Why is this terminology confusing

I heuristically use patterns in terminology to either predict, better understand, or remember terminology. This can lead to false inferences sometimes. An example is when there's a prefix like [*homo-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homo-), there is often an antonymous prefix [*hetero-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hetero-). When something is worth using the prefix for *same*, it has often suggested that there is a corresponding prefix for *other* or *different*.

In statistics we contrast [homoscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity) from [heteroschedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity). In biology we distinguish [heterostasis from homostasis](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/405752/pdf). In chemistry we distinguish [homogenous mixtures and heterogenous mixtures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_and_heterogeneous_mixtures).

Not to say that we should upend the current state of mathematical terminology, but I hope this post helps someone else with this *gotcha* of mathematical jargon.

Comment: If they are of different types, what kind of structure could the map possibly preserve?

Comment: Exactly! The question arises from the distinction being made without examples of both types.

Comment: That is to say, I have yet to find any mention in textbooks, proofwiki, wolfram, or wikipedia on such a thing. So why make the classification of homomorphisms if they seem to be the only morphisms we talk about.

Comment: My intuition would be that "heteromorphism" would be an appropriate term, if such things exist at all.

Comment: "Structure-preserving map between structures of different types" is a contradiction in terms. The introduction of the term "morphism" is due to the fact that morphisms are not necessarily even maps at all, not because they can go between different types of structure. (E.g. consider [**cobordism categories**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism#Categorical_aspects).)

Comment: Is "morphism" polysemic?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Morphism.html

Comment: @Galen "Is "morphism" polysemic?" Both "morphism" and "homomorphism" are polysemic (I learned a new word today!), but "morphism" is more general than "homomorphism" (compare with "rectangle" vs. "square"). That said, if you swap the two nobody will really object as long as the context is clear; I've definitely seen "homomorphism of topological spaces" used in writing in place of "continuous map," and while it's a bit cringy it's perfectly comprehensible. Ultimately I think you're looking for a sharper terminological distinction here than actually exists.

Comment: "Functor" isn't quite right, but I think it has about the right flavor.  Because I don't really know category theory, I'll avoid words which may have technical meaning:  a *function* is a doohicky which each objects and morphisms in one category, and poops out objects and morphisms in another category. To me, a "structure preserving map between two different types of algebraic structures" sounds like a kind of functor, e.g. there is a monic functor (I think I'm using the word goodly) which sends rings to groups by "forgetting" the multiplication.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Except a functor *is* a map between two similar types of structure - namely, between two categories. It's really tautologous: as soon as we have a notion of "map between," we've established a common context for the structures involved.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree, but my reading of the question is that the asker is looking for a term which describes, for example, a map from an abelian group to ring, which preserves structure.  The closest thing that I can think of is a functor:  group elements are mapped to ring elements, and the group operation is preserved as the addition in the ring.  Such a mapping is essentially the action of a functor from the category of abelian groups to the category of rings, no? (Again, I am not a category theorist).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Some functors can be understood as acting on individual elements of the objects (when that even makes sense), such as the forgetful functor from rings to groups, but that's not always the case. For example, consider the map sending a group to its partial order of subgroups. This is functorial in the obvious sense, but doesn't really have an associated "action on elements."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed; I was not claiming that every functor is of the kind requested by the asker, only that the kind of thing requested by the asker looks like an example of a  (specific kind of) functor.

Comment: @NoahSchweber " I think you're looking for a sharper terminological distinction here than actually exists."

Yup!

Comment: @Arthur What do you think of how Galois theory in relation to this question?

Comment: [For example, Galois theory establishes a connection between certain fields and groups: two algebraic structures of different kinds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632251/whats-a-morphism-between-algebraic-structures-of-different-types)

Comment: [Galois theory provides a connection between field theory and group theory. Using Galois theory, certain problems in field theory can be reduced to group theory, which is in some sense simpler and better understood.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a homomorphism is not a mapping between two algebraic structures of the same type - it's not clear what "type" would mean anyway. A homomorphism is a structure preserving map between two algebraic structures. Specifically, if we define "algebraic structure" to mean "set with a binary operation on it", then a homomorphism is a mapping from $(A, \cdot)$ to $(B, \circ)$ satisfying

$$f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\circ f(y)$$

A homomorphism is not a more specific type of "morphism", homomorphism and morphism are just two different words used in two different fields of math (homomorphism in algebra and morphism in category theory).

Now, if we have in mind a specific kind of algebraic structure like a group, we might talk about a "homomorphism of groups" to refer specifically to refer to a homomorphism between groups, but that doesn't mean you're not allowed to use the term homomorphism to refer to a mapping between any two algebraic structures.

Comment: I'm not saying these are academic sources, but they might help you appreciate where the confusion comes from.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism)
[Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homomorphism.html)